# Is there a sandbox version of the Github api v3 for testing apps?

Tags: github

I am developing a Github v3 api app, and I need to be able to test it's functionality while developing without mutating actual data. Is there a sandbox api available?

Comment: I suppose you can't just create a test account and use its repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is simply to create one's own (public) sandbox repo to play/test with.

Even the [Spoon-Knife](https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife) repo from octocat GitHub account isn't available for direct contribution, but is only there for [testing forks](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo).